# Lord krishna is in tenth dimension

Tags: vishnu, krishna, gods, bhagavata-purana

It is said in shrimad bhagvat that lord krishna is the greatest lord of all and he is living in tenth dimension but lord vishnu is in 6th dimension and krishna is incarnation of vishnu so how it is possible ??

Comment: Can you mention the sources of your claims too, to make the question more complete and aid in answering it?

Comment: Sources that vishnu is in tenth dimension is from vishnu puran and of krishna is mentioned.I m asking that how it is possible that if greatest is krishna then he is manly incarnation of vishnu

Comment: Where did you read this exactly? Share the link.

Comment: It would be more clear if you cite verses/sloka from Puranas.

Comment: You read it wrong, lord krishna is in 20th dimension while Lord Vishnu is reincarnation of Lord Krishna himself.

Comment: What is meant here by 'dimension'?

Comment: Means like we live in 3dimensional world like that lord krishna lives in 10 th dimensional world according to shrimadbhagvata